# Javav Sound selecting DataLines and Ports at runtime

Tags: java, javasound

I understand the concept of `TargetDataLine` and `SourceDataLine` and I have written a program to list them as well as the `Ports` and the available `Controls` for each. For the test progam I have an onboard mic, on board speakers, a line in, a speaker jack and an audio interface with two inputs and one output. The inputs on the interface are treated as left and right so I'm not sure how I would differentiate between the two if they act as one stereo input.

I want to be able to select the `DataLine` I want to use for either recording or playback at runtime. How can I identify and separate inputs and outputs to list them and allow a user to select a specific one to use? And if anyone has any suggestions for handling the interface input as two mono inputs That would be helpful as well. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To convert two mono lines into stereo requires interleaving the left and right, one "sample" at a time. The size of the sample depends on your bit depth. For example, 16-bit encoding consumes two bytes. So, take two bytes from the left, then two bytes from the right. Repeat for the duration of the lines.

There may be prebuilt methods that will help you with this. Check out the section in the Java Sound tutorials section on converting formats--it's like the 4th or 5th section of the sound tutorials, and happens to also be the best written of the bunch if I remember correctly. (Actual sample code provided, unlike much of the rest of this very difficult tutorial.)

I'm not sure how selecting a line or port is different from programming selecting anything else. You make a list, and the user clicks a button associated with the item, or selects the item from a drop down, then you plug it in.

I have a theremin where I made a menubar that allows one to select a mixer line. It just populates a radio button set with names of the mixers that are found. When you select the item the listener directs one to install the associated mixer.

Comment: The problem I've had with the Sound API is it all seems pretty dated, I think it was written for Java 5, but I'll revisit the section on converting audio formats. 

And my interface problem is the other way around. There are two inputs on the interface, there's an XLR and a 1/4" input,  which I guess would be Ports. Both ports are treated as one stereo DataLine, the XLR is the left channel and the 1/4" is the right. I want to keep those inputs separate and be able to control each as if it were its own mono DataLine, for example mute one and record the other.

Comment: If you bring your DataLine as a single TargetDataLine, you will have access to the individual bytes, one buffer's worth at a time. Instead of just handing off the buffer to the next stage, you can "do something" with the bytes. (See also the very last part of the "working with controls" section of the audio tutorial.) That something can include (a) taking the bytes and convert to audio data data, (b) applying a volume multiplier (usually a float between 0 and 1), (c) converting the result back to bytes. You could also sum the two channels at stage (b) or mix them however you like.

Comment: Thanks that's a great idea,I hadn't considered actually manipulating the bytes to create my own controls. Are you familiar with PortAudio in Java? I've been reading about that and JNI interfaces, it seems like a possible solution but I'm curious how much portability you loose to get better control over the hardware.

Comment: There is a lot one can do with the bytes directly, not just one-sample-at-a-time ops like mixing and panning, but convolution-type effects like filtering or echo/reverb. Java is fast enough to do these things if done right. I have no experience with PortAudio or JNI. All my experiments have been with Java Sound: mixer, theremin, fm synthesis, limited wave-table synthesis, a bit of filtering, echo, varispeed playback.

Comment: Thank you I appreciate your input.